# Java CompletableFuture.allOf().whenComplete() with multiple exceptions

Tags: java, completable-future

## Problem

In Java Official Doc, it says

> `public static CompletableFuture<Void> allOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)`

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete. If any of the given CompletableFutures complete exceptionally, then the returned CompletableFuture also does so, with a CompletionException holding this exception as its cause.

The doc doesn't specify the case when multiple given CompletableFutures complete exceptionally. For example, in the following code snippet, what will the exception and its cause be if c1, c2, c3 all complete exceptionally?

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(c1, c2, c3)
        .whenComplete((result, exception) -> {
            if (exception != null) {
                System.out.println("exception occurs");
                System.err.println(exception);
            } else {
                System.out.println("no exception, got result: " + result);
            }
        })
```

---

## My experiment 1

Create a completableFuture `signal_1` and `signal_2` that both completes exceptionally fast. The output shows `signal_1` gets passed to `.whenComplete()` as the cause of exception.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {

    private static void runTasks(int i) {
        System.out.printf("-- input: %s --%n", i);

        CompletableFuture<Void> signal_1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
        signal_1.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("Oh noes!"));

        CompletableFuture<Integer> signal_2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 16 / i);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(signal_1, signal_2)
                .thenApplyAsync(justVoid -> {
                     final int num = signal_2.join();
                     System.out.println(num);
                     return num;
                })
                .whenComplete((result, exception) -> {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        System.out.println("exception occurs");
                        System.err.println(exception);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("no exception, got result: " + result);
                    }
                })
                .thenApplyAsync(input -> input * 3)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runTasks(0);
    }

}
```

### Output

```
-- input: 0 --
exception occurs
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Oh noes!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

## My experiment 2

Added a 3 second sleep before `signal_1` completes exceptionally, so `signal_1` should completes **after** `signal_2`. However, the output still shows `signal_1` gets passed to `.whenComplete()` as the cause of exception.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {

    static ExecutorService customExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private static void runTasks(int i) {
        System.out.printf("-- input: %s --%n", i);

        CompletableFuture<Void> signal_1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Oh noes!");
        }, customExecutorService);

        CompletableFuture<Integer> signal_2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 16 / i);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(signal_1, signal_2)
                .thenApplyAsync(justVoid -> {
                     final int num = signal_2.join();
                     System.out.println(num);
                     return num;
                })
                .whenComplete((result, exception) -> {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        System.out.println("exception occurs");
                        System.err.println(exception);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("no exception, got result: " + result);
                    }
                })
                .thenApplyAsync(input -> input * 3)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runTasks(0);
        customExecutorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

### Output

```
-- input: 0 --
exception occurs
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Oh noes!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Probably the exception of the first one that completed exceptionally, because a completable future can only be completed once.

Comment: Since the docs don’t say anything on the matter, you probably cannot make any assumptions about which of the exceptions will be provided by the allOf future.

Comment: Could also be the first one in the list that completed exceptionally. I've checked the source code [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java), and `allOf` creates a "tree of completions" from the given array. So, there is some structure to which one completes the returned completable future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is largely a repeat of what VGR said in the comments, but it is an important rule of thumb that deserves a full write-up.

In Java, there is an important concept called [Unspecified Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior#Definition). In short, if the docs do not explicitly define what happens in a specific scenario, then the implementation is free to do literally whatever it chooses to, within reason and within the bounds of the other rules that are explicitly defined. This is important because there are several different manifestations of that.

For starters, the result could be platform specific. For some machines, leaving the behaviour undefined allows for some special optimizations that still return a "correct" result. And since Java prioritizes both similar/same behaviour on all platforms as well as performance, choosing not to specify certain aspects of execution allows them to stay true to that promise while still getting the optimization benefits that come with specific platforms.

Another example is when the act of unifying behaviour into a specific action is not currently feasible. If I had to guess, this is most likely what Java is actually doing. In certain instances, Java will design a component with *the potential* for certain functionality, but will stop short of actually defining and implementing it. This is usually done in instances where building out a full blown solution would be more effort than it is worth, amongst other reasons. Ironically enough, CompletableFuture itself is a good example of this. Java 5 introduced Future's, but only as an interface with generic functionality. CompletableFuture, the implmementation which came in Java 8, later fleshed out and defined all the unspecified behaviour left over from the Java 5 interface.

And lastly, they may avoid defining specified behaviour if choosing specified behaviour would stifle the flexibility of possible implementations. Currently, the method you showed does not have any specified behaviour about ***which*** exception will be thrown when the futures fail. This allows any class that later extends CompletableFuture to be able to specify that behaviour for themselves while still maintaining [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If you don't already know, LSP says that if a Child class extends a Parent class, then that Child class must follow all the rules of the Parent class. As a result, if the rules (specified behaviour) of the class are too restrictive, then you prevent future implementations/extensions of this class from being able to function without breaking LSP. There are likely some extensions for CompletableFuture that allow you to define exactly what type of Exception is thrown when calling the method. But that's the point - they are extensions that you can choose to ***opt-in*** to. If they define it for you, then you are stuck with it unless you implement it yourself, or you go outside the languages standard library.

Comment: I like the answer much. I'd still say that being aware of specific implementation details is worth it and you can make decisions based on it, or program around it. You obviously shouldn't make your code dependent on such details. E.g., in the context of this question: Yes, there is no guaranty that it's always the first occurred exception, or the last one, or whatever. But, due to the implementation, it's maybe always the first in the list, or whatever, and based on this, you can decide in what order you pass your futures. E.g., when exceptions A and B happen and you prefer to know about A.

Comment: @akuzminykh I agree with your first point. Knowing implementation details will often times help you, even if the implementation changes under you. While you shouldn't let it be the first thing you learn about a tool, knowing it will allow you to see and solve problems before they ever occur. Obviously, the better designed the tool, the less need there is to look under the hood. But that's usually because many other people have already done that for you.